# Series Generating Functions and intervals?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In paragraph [9.24. "Set Returning Functions"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-srf.html) of the PostgreSQL 9.5 manual is an example with "generate_series" with which I disagree.

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2008-03-01 00:00'::timestamp,
                              '2008-03-04 12:00', '10 hours');

    generate_series   
---------------------  
2008-03-01 00:00:00  
2008-03-01 10:00:00  
2008-03-01 20:00:00  
2008-03-02 06:00:00  
2008-03-02 16:00:00 
2008-03-03 02:00:00  
2008-03-03 12:00:00  
2008-03-03 22:00:00 
2008-03-04 08:00:00 
(9 rows)
```

I explain why, if we talk about intervals of 10 hours in length, then the line: "2008-03-04 08:00:00" should not be displayed, since there are only 4 hours left.

The last line should be `2008-03-03 22:00:00`.

With the problem of outputting the intervals entirely, I recently encountered how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are interpreting it wrong.

`generate_series()` starts with the first value and continues adding the interval until the value would exceed the end value.

That is exactly how it is defined and exactly what your example is doing.  The boundaries are the start and end.

A simpler example uses numbers.  This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(0, 22, 5);
```

returns a series of multiples of 5 up to 22.  That is, the last value is 20.

Comment: means, "generate_series ()" can not display the number of full intervals?

Comment: @VikaSmirnova . . . Exactly.  It generates the *starting* values that are within the range.  Amusingly, I had never thought of your confusion, but it actually makes sense.  `Generate_series()` is about the the starting values, not about full intervals.